# Fault Code:HTTP String:Could not connect to host

Tags: php, soap, ubuntu-12.04

When trying to get the FEDEX rate using a **SOAP** request (I'm using **PHP** with **XAMPP**), I'm getting the following error:

> **Fault**
>
> Code:HTTP    String:Could not connect to host

in this code:

```
<?php 

    require_once('library/fedex-common.php');

    $path_to_wsdl = "wsdl/RateService_v13.wsdl";     
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); 

    $client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); 
    try { 
        if(setEndpoint('changeEndpoint')) { 
            $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint('endpoint')); 
        } 
        $response = $client ->getRates($request); 
    } catch (SoapFault $exception) { 
        printFault($exception, $client); 
    }

?>
```

This happens on Ubuntu only. The same code (also using XAMPP) works fine on Windows, however.

Comment: Please show us the code you're using to do this.

Comment: <?php

require_once('library/fedex-common.php');
$path_to_wsdl = "wsdl/RateService_v13.wsdl";

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
 
$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1));
$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
 'UserCredential' =>array(
  'Key' => getProperty('key'), 
  'Password' => getProperty('password')
 )
); 
try 
{
 if(setEndpoint('changeEndpoint'))
 {
  $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint('endpoint'));
 }
 
 $response = $client ->getRates($request);
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
   printFault($exception, $client);        
}

?>

Comment: The error happens in that line? I suspect you have some actual SOAP code lying around that performs the request.

Comment: Actually no code error it's a fault.I can't connect the host while request.